# How do I redirect all traffic to a new domain except for the home page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

So I'm trying to redirect traffic that goes to other pages using htaccess from a domain to a new subdomain but I'd like to keep traffic to the homepage there.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$

RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/newsubdomain\.domain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

This just redirects everything to the new subdomain. That's where I'd like some help, how can I keep the traffic that comes to the homepage on olddmain.com and redirect queries to olddomain/post and have them go to newsubdomain.domain.com/post

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> This just redirects everything to the new subdomain.

No it doesn't. (If everything is being redirected then either something else is doing that or you are seeing a cached redirect.)

The directives as posted actually do the exact opposite of what you're trying to do. These directives only redirect the homepage (ie. requests for the document root).

To redirect everything, except the homepage, you can do something like the following at the top of the `.htaccess` file:

```
# Redirect everything except the homepage
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule !^$ https://newsubdomain.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `!^$` matches everything except the root (an *empty* URL-path).

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

Additional notes:

- There is no need to backslash-escape colons, slashes and dots in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string (2nd argument) - this is an "ordinary" string, not a regex. (This unnecessary escaping is quite typical of an attempt at using cPanel's "redirect" generation.)
- I assume this should be HTTPS, not HTTP?
- The two *conditions* (`RewriteCond` directives) can be combined into one.